# How can ipc communicate in real time if we have the master process execute the ping command?

Tags: electron, ipc

Support there is a scenario like below:
react calls the node.js ping module to communicate with the Ping module in real time and display the results on the react interface. How to implement this in Electron?

we can do it in renderer process or main process.

I have several questions about it:

1. If we do this in the renderer process, how do we achieve real-time communication?
2. How can ipc communicate in real time if we have the master process execute the ping command?

because ipcRenderer communicate with ipcMain is back-and-forth interaction, so how to implement the keep-alive communication?

such as, when ping get one reply, it will push to the caller.

```
% ping example.com
PING example.com (151.101.2.165): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 151.101.2.165: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=141.118 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.2.165: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=132.017 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
64 bytes from 151.101.2.165: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=144.409 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.2.165: icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=133.365 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.2.165: icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=142.448 ms
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? How do you specify "performance"? If it's just about displaying results of a ping, then it doesn't matter if the ping is executed in the main process or in the renderer, since the only thing that will be different is the latency between getting the result and displaying it, does it?